# Why isn’t the integral of $x^2$ from $0$ to $5$ equal to the integral of $\sqrt x$ from $0$ to $25$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, inverse-function

My calculator says that the former is 41.67, and that the latter is 83.34. Why is that? Shouldn’t they be equal?

Comment: Why do you think they should be equal? It's different functions on different intervals.

Comment: If you are thinking about areas, sketch the regions whose areas are given by these integrals. You'll see why they aren't equal but are closely related: there is a reason why their sum equals $125$.

Comment: Just draw it. We have the same areas.

Comment: There is also a clue that one is half of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral of $x^2$ from $x=0$ to $x=5$ measures the area **below** the graph of $y=x^2$ from $x=0$ to $x=5$.

Now the inverse function $y=\sqrt{x}$ from $x=0$ to $x=25$ corresponds to reflecting the original function across the line $y=x$. So the integral from $x=0$ to $x=25$ of $\sqrt{x}$ is the area below the graph of $y=\sqrt{x}$ from $x=0$ to $x=5$, i.e., the area **left of** the graph of $y=x^2$ from $x=0$ to $x=5$.

So the areas are not equal, but their sum should be the area of the rectangle from $x=0$ to $x=5$ and $y=0$ to $y=25$, i.e., $125$.

Answer (score 4):

Let me answer your question with a picture.

$$\int_0^5 x^2 \, dx$$ is the area of the red region while

$$\int_0^{25} \sqrt{y} \, dy$$

is the area of the blue region.

I have also constructed the line $y=5x$ to illustrate that they are not equal.

[image]